# Using git, can I checkout a branch in Visual Studio without deleting the old branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to git, and we're just now switching from TFS 2010 to git.  We created a new master branch and 3 subsidiary branches off of the master on our remote server.  I installed the VS plugin and cloned the remote repository, which downloaded all of the master files into the local repository.

Now, when I make a new local branch off of one of the other remote branches, it deletes all of the local files for the master branch and replaces them with the files for the newly checked out branch.  When I checkout master again, it again deletes the new branch locally and replaces it with the master branch.

Is there a way to retain the local files so that switching between branches happens quickly and doesn't have to re-download every file all the time?

Comment: Git doesn't download anything when you checkout a branch. It should be a really fast operation. Is there any chance you are storing very large files in the branch and/or that your local repository is actually a mapped network device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in TFVC, where only the branches that you want are downloaded, Git downloads the whole repository to your local disk. From this repository it creates the working folder with the files at the version/branch you checked out.

When you switch from one branch to another, git replaces only the files that are different from its local cache. No files are transferred when switching.

This has the impact though that, unlike in TFVC, it's not possible to have two branches open at the same time in the same repository (TFVC workspace), instead you'd need to clone the repository again (you can make a local copy of the whole repo) and check out a different branch in your second repository. The same was true in TFVC when you wanted the same branch a two different versions. In order to do that you'd have to create a second workspace.

The underlying reason for this all is that, in git, a branch is nothing more than a pointer to a version. and switching between branches is the same as switching between versions. And because Git has a local copy of all the changes ever made in the repo, switching is fast and efficient (up to a certain size repo of course).

Comment: That's possible to have 2 branches checkouted with one repository without being obliged to clone it again. Look at `git worktree`.

Comment: Nice, though Visual Studio up to 2015 likely won't understand that. It's git features are still a bit limited. 2017 is going to change that quite a bit.

Comment: Visual studio will never be able to do what git could do. So, sometimes, we should accept to do things outside of it ;-)

Comment: Totally agree. Just trying to make the shock a little less :).

Comment: Apparently, I was just completely misunderstanding how git works.  When I was doing the checkout, it wasn't downloading the remote branch; it was just setting up all of the local differences.  It was just taking a long time because there were over 500K file differences between the branches.  I'm guessing that somebody screwed something up when making them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Usually git has all branches locally already, so there are no additional downloads if a branch is checked out.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to say other than that's not what's happening for me.  If I have "Branch 1" checked out and then checkout "Branch 2" and then look in Windows explorer at the directory, Branch 1 is gone and is replaced by Branch 2.  If I switch back, it does the same thing.  I wouldn't care if it didn't take 10 minutes to redownload every file.  In TFS, I could have as many branches mapped locally as I wanted, and when I pulled latest, it would download the differences.  It wouldn't always redownload the entire file structure.

Comment: Sure, files are replaced by changing a branch. Wouldn't make sense without, right?  But also branches are a snapshot of file states, so Jogging to download really. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell for a detailed described of the branching concept of git.

Comment: I think OP is actually missing the concepts of [working/stage/commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States). When you check out a branch, Git simply updates the working area. The branch is not deleted. Usually there's no need to have two branches available simultaneously. Git workflow involves branching and merging frequently. OP's going to have to "forget" a few concepts that they were used to in order to best use Git.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a repository, all the history with all the branches and all the files are downloaded and put, with some other data, in a '.git' folder.

When you check out a branch, the workspace is updated with the local files (no download!)

Normally, a check out is quite quick. If that's not the case, you have a problem with the files that you put in it.

Unlike TFVC, you must not commit binary files or big files. 
My advice is that you should clean your history ( surely using 'BFG repo cleaner')

If that's not **really** possible, perhaps you should use 'git-lfs' (supported by Tfs and other git servers).

But, in short term, perhaps you could have a look at 'git worktree' if you want to check out 2 branches in 2 different directories like what you did with TFVC...

But it will not help you get the real power of git :-(

Answer (score 0):

Branches in git are not deleted, if you do checkout another one. Like stated in the above comments, the documentation mentioned in [working/staging/commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States) do explain this pretty nicely.

Git is distributed, and therefor all Branches are stored on each machine, where you have fetched/pulled it. The whole history of the repository is stored on your machine.

Obviously there is a way to delete Branches (local as well as remote), but this is not part of the current question.